# AWS EC2 PHP session_start with permission denied

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, session

I have an strange issue related with PHP an the session save path. I have configured in my php.ini the session.save_path = "/tmp", and I know that is correctly configured since in the server I could type the following command and the command result seems to be fine.

```
$ php -i | grep session.save_path
session.save_path => /tmp => /tmp
```

However, when I am trying to start a session from php code, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_7ktfe84jqca3ga6ftk6fsrurv6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

So the path here is totally different from /tmp configured in php.ini.

Is there any reason for this behavior? I have checked that in my code there is no any call to session_save_path to change the default save path.

The server with this problem is an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: When you say "from php code", do you mean like `php -r` or through a web server?

Comment: In many servers, CLI PHP uses a different `php.ini`... and you'll usually need to restart the web server after making changes.

Comment: From a php file located in a web server and loaded from web browser. I have also set session_save_path manually in php code just before start_session but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, and seems a configuration problem. I have opened a phpinfo in the server and see the following:

```
Directive            Local Value            Master value
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /tmp
```

The local value pointing /var/lib/php/session seems to be the problem as this directory is not writable by server user. I did not know anything about local and master value, and after some digging in google I read the following:

> "Master Value" (from php.ini) could be overridden with "Local Value"
>   in httpd.conf, .htaccess or other Apache configuration with php_value
>   directive.

So after looking around server files i found /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf which contains:

```
#
Apache specific PHP configuration options
those can be override in each configured vhost
#
php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path "/var/lib/php/session"
```

So there is the problem, this php.conf is overwritting default php.ini configuration. I can comment this last line wih "#" and restart the server and all is working as expected again.

Hope this help.

Comment: worked for me!!. I had the same issue where my PHP 7.4 session is working only for the same page, and when I was checking session on another page it was missing and the strange thing was 'echo session_id();' wasn't showing anything. when I checked PHP info the session.save_path had different values for master and local. changing in "/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf" fixed my issue. Note - I had tried each and everything on the internet but nothing worked except this. I am an EC2 user with ALB using PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add this to your elastic beanstalk project.config file:

"/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf" :
    content: |
      php_value session.save_path "/tmp"

that will just set the session save path for you

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect through ssh (if you have configured the key/pair initially) and change the permission of the folder so it's owned by webpp user

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution for this one is to put the following before your session_start();

```
<?php
$dir = sys_get_temp_dir();
session_save_path($dir);
?>
```

[... taken from here](http://technosophos.com/2013/10/09/getting-php-sessions-work-aws-elastic-beanstalk.html).